# VBA: Workbookfunction if Dropdown Changes Call Sub with different sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet function that automatically calls CopyValues once dropdown in E4 changes on Sheet Debt Detail. This macro only runs if the sheet name is "Debt Detail" otherwise it is going to Exit Sub. This macro worked well until now. I added another sheet called "Borrower Statement", which is supposed to call BorrowerStatementCall if E4 changes in Sheet Borrower Statement.

I need to modify the existing Workbook function to accomplish this.
Below is the existing code. Any help and suggestions on how to accomplish this would be appreciated:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

If sh.Name <> "Debt Detail" Then Exit Sub

    If Target.Address = Range("$E$4").Address Then

Call CopyValues

Range("A1").ClearOutline
Range("d2").Select

End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: There's no reference to "Borrower Statement" in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some suggestions on your code:

- Indent your code
- Use at least some error handling if you're turning off screenupdating and other stuff
- No need for the Call statement

**Code:**

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    On Error GoTo CleanFail
    
    ' Exit if modified cell is not E4
    If Target.Address <> "$E$4" Then Exit Sub

    ' Turn off stuff to speed up process (only if modified cell is E4)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Check the sheet name and call procedure accordingly
    Select Case sh.Name
    Case "Debt Detail"
        ' Do stuff if it's the target sheet
        CopyValues ' Calls the sub CopyValues
        
        sh.Range("A1").ClearOutline
        sh.Range("D2").Select
    
    Case "Borrower Statement"
        ' Do stuff if it's the target sheet
        BorrowerStatementCall ' calls the sub BorrowerStatementCall
        
    End Select

CleanExit:
    ' Turn on stuff again
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub

CleanFail:
    MsgBox "An error occurred:" & Err.Description
    GoTo CleanExit

End Sub
```

Let me know if it works